# Microbatch loading into Redshift - Some practical questions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

We are designing our workflow for doing microbatch loading of data into redshift. Basically we get a series of requests coming through an API. The API pumps those in a queue that is later processed, each item is ETLd, and finally saved into a ready-to-load file in S3. So the steps are:

1. Client sends request to API.
2. API picks up and transforms into JSON
3. API queues JSON in queue
4. Consumer picks up from queue
5. Depending on contents it writes request in the relevant file (represents the table to load stuff into)

My questions are around the coordination of this flow. At what point do we fire the copy command from S3 into Redshift? I mean this is an ongoing stream of data and each data batch is a minute wide. Are there any AWS tools that do this thing for us or should we write this ourselves.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda is made for this use case.

Alternatively, if your queue is a Kafka queue, you might find secor (https://github.com/pinterest/secor) useful. It dumps queue data into s3 where it can then be copied to Redshirt.

Spotify's Luigi or AWS Data Pipeline are both good options for orchestrating the copy command if you go the secor route.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've written similar logic couple of times, and it's not an easy task. There is lots of complexity there. You can use these article as a reference for the [architecture](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx2ANLN1PGELDJU/Best-Practices-for-Micro-Batch-Loading-on-Amazon-Redshift).

These days, instead of implementing yourself, you may want to look at the [Amazon Kinesis Firehose](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html). It'll handle both the S3 logic and writing into Redshift for you.